# rails Geocoder gem order by location from me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-geocoder

I have Place model with lat and long fields.
  So i need to select all places and order them using my geoposition.
  I think that i need to use **Geocoder** gem.

So user send to me his lat & long
  and i need to do smth like

```
  Place.where(status: 1).and order them using my lat long.
```

How can i do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the `near` method:

```
Place.where(status: 1).near( "Party City, Utah", 20 ) # Finds places within 20 miles
```

This will grab all `Place` records that are within a specific radius of the given location. In this case, your location is "Party City, Utah". You can add additional arguments to the `near` method to limit the number of results, and also edit the radius of your query.

More information in the [GeoCoder Docs](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#for-activerecord-models)

Comment: as i understand, near can find me only places near to me on range (for xample 10 km)

Comment: Yes, but you can alter the range distance. Set it to 1000km if you'd like

Comment: but if i want to select all Places from Moscow and for example from Vilnius - how i can know radius?
Moscow = 10.times Vilnius

Comment: Yes, exactly. You'll want to use `near` because it forces results to be returned by the relative distance to a given location. You should, however, "chunk" or "paginate" your results to prevent server load.

Comment: So only .near() without range?

Comment: You have to set a range, just make it a big range. Default measurement is in miles, so you'll want to change that to km as well